# Open apps using node.js spawn

Tags: node.js, spawn, xcrun

I'm trying to do a little application with node.js that would run on mac and execute some commands.

I've successfully used spawn to run command lines such as xcodebuild, but xcrun doesn't seems to work when I try to open the iOS Simulator.
I can open on terminal by typing:

```
xcrun instruments -w 'iPhone 5s (9.2)' -t <template>
```

But if I use node and try to use spawn like this:

```
var args = ['instruments', '-w', `iPhone 5s (9.2)`, '-t', 'noTemp'];
var xcrun = spawn('xcrun', args);
```

So it got me thinking that maybe it had some limitation opening apps? I tried to run:

```
var args = ['/Applications/Spotify.app'];
var xcrun = spawn('open', args);
```

And nothing happens. I couldn't find anything related to that. My question is: is there anyway to open apps using node.js spawn? If there is, does someone know what's the problem with my code?

Here's the full code if needed:

```
var args = ['instruments', '-w', `${fullDevice}`, '-t', 'noTemp'];
var xcrun = spawn('xcrun', args);

xcrun.stdout.on('data', (data)=>{
    console.log(data.toString('utf8'));
})

xcrun.on('close', (code) => {
    socket.emit({
        time: commands.getCurrentTime(),
        type: 'success',
        log: 'Device booted...'
    });
    callback();
    if (code !== 0) {
        console.log(`open process exited with code ${code}`);
    }
});
```

OBS: if I run this piece of code the application doesn't terminate, the program doesn't continue and nothing happens.

EDIT: Changed:

```
xcrun.on('data', (data)=>{
```

To:

```
xcrun.stdout.on('data', (data)=>{
```

Comment: I'm guessing in the first code example you meant to put `'xcrun'` instead of `'open'`?

Comment: Right, fixed it! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Spawned processes have two separate streams for [stdout](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdout) and [stderr](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stderr), so you will need to listen for data on those objects and not the spawned process object itself:

```
xcrun.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data.toString());
});
xcrun.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was one line above. Not sure why, but there's a socket.emit call that is wrong and actually hold the program's execution.